# XNA-Moving rotated camera(view) relative to world

Tags: c#, xna

So I've been trying to get this to work but no luck so far, hopefully you can help. The thing is I have a camera in my project that the user can freely move with mouse and buttons. 
Currently like so:
`move = new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * moveSpeed;
      move = new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * moveSpeed;
...`

And then I just add move vector to cameraPos vector:  `cameraPos += move`

Then problem is if I rotate the camera and then try to move, for example down, it will not move straight down but in a certain angle. I am assuming this is due to moving on local axis. But what I want to do is to move on a world axis. Is something like that possible, or do I have to somehow calculate the angle and then move on more than one axis?

Best regards!

EDIT:
I am rotating the camera where  `cameraPos`  is the current position of the camera and  `rotation`  is the current rotation of the camera. And this is the code to rotate the camera:

```
void Update()
{
    ...
    if(pressed)
    {
        int newY = currentY - oldY;
        pitch -= rotSpeed * newY;
    }
    Rotate();
}

void Rotate()
{
    rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch);
    Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(cameraPos, rotation);
    Vector3 lookAt = cameraPos + transformedReference;
    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos, lookAt, Vector3.Up);

    oldY = currentY;
}
```

Ihope this is more readable.

Comment: Please show code you use for camera rotation. I presume you're generating the view matrix with `Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos, targetPos, up)` metod? Also show your world matrix for drawing the said objects. Might be that you're inadvertently applying rotation to your world, instead of just the camera.

Comment: Thats right, that is the code for view matrix. For rotation I use: rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch);
Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(cameraPos, rotation);
Vector3 lookAt = cameraPos + transformedReference;
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos, lookAt, Vector3.Up);

I am sorry I cant use <code> tags for some reason.

Comment: I don't quite understand - are you rotating the camera, or are you rotating the object? Put the relevant code into your question - it's easier to read there. Also specify what `transformedReference` is.

Comment: @user1806687: FYI: There's no need to add `SOLVED` to the question title. It is sufficient to simply tick off (i.e. accept) an answer, as you have done, and that will mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using:

```
Vector3 v;
if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
   v = new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * moveSpeed;
... //Other code for moving down,left,right

if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.V))
    view *= Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(-5f) * rotSpeed); //Multiplying view Matrix to create rotation

view *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(v); //Multiplying view Matrix to create movement by Vector3 v
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're already saving the direction you're looking at in a `Vector3`. Replace your method with this:

```
direction.Normalize();
var move = direction * moveSpeed;
cameraPos += move;
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. The camera is facing towards an object, and I want to move the camera, for example downwards, while the camera is still facing that object. 

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/examplead.png/

Comment: I am sorry, I am bad at explaining :/. 
Lets say, I have a camera that is rotated on x axis by 37°. Now if I use Vector3(0,-1,0) to move the "camera", it will move downwards, but not in a straight line because (I think), its local axises are not parallel to global axises(because of the rotation). My question is how can I move the "camera" downwards in a straight line(perpendicular to global x axis).